# Extract substring passing a variable to cut

Tags: bash, unix

Is it possible to do something like this in `bash` with `cut`:

```
strLf="JJT9879YGTT"
strZ=(2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 11)
numZ=${#strZ[@]}
for ((ctZ=0; ctZ<${numZ}; ctZ++))
do
   lenThis=${strZ[${ctZ}]}
   fetch=$(echo "${strLf}" | cut -c 1-${lenThis})
done
```

Through successive loops, I want `${fetch}` to contain `"JJ" "JJT" "JJT98" "JJT987" "JJT9879YG" "JJT9879YGTT"`, etc, according to the indexes given by `strZ`.

Or is there some other way I need to be doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `${string:position:length}` to get the `length` characters of `$string` starting in `position`.

```
$ s="JJT9879YGTT"
$ echo ${s:0:2}
JJ
$ echo ${s:0:3}
JJT
```

And also using variables:

```
$ t=5
$ echo ${s:0:$t}
JJT98
```

So if you put all these values in an array, you can loop through them and use its value as a `length` argument saying `${string:0:length}`:

```
strLf="JJT9879YGTT"
strZ=(2 3 5 6 9 11)
for i in ${strZ[@]}; do
    echo "${strLf:0:$i}"
done
```

For your given string it returns this to me:

```
$ for i in ${strZ[@]}; do echo "${strLf:0:$i}"; done
JJ
JJT
JJT98
JJT987
JJT9879YG
JJT9879YGTT
```

Comment: you should change the array name on your 3rd example to `strZ`

Answer (score 0):

```
words="JJT9879YGTT"
strZ=(2 3 5 6 9 11)
for i in "${strZ[@]}"
do
  echo ${words:0:$i}
done
```

---

Output:

```
JJ
JJT
JJT98
JJT987
JJT9879YG
JJT9879YGTT
```

---

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/xQLWYR)

Answer (score 0):

Realised my mistake - I was using commas in the array to identify elements.

So instead of what I was using:

```
strZ=(2, 3, 5, 6, 9, 11)
```

I have to use:

```
strZ=(2 3 5 6 9 11)
```

It works for `cut` as well.